# Moving a dynamic body to a target position using mouse joint (without touches) in box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I am trying to move a ball(dynamic body) to a target location using the mouse joints.

I am having a shoot button, when I tap on to it I am calling this method where my ball is created.

```
-(void) addNewSpriteAtPosition:(CGPoint)p withAngle:(CGFloat)angle
{
    CCLOG(@"Add sprite %0.2f x %02.f",p.x,p.y);

    angle = 270-angle;
    sprite1 = [PhysicsSprite spriteWithTexture:spriteTexture_ rect:CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,22,22)];                        
    [self addChild:sprite1 z:0 tag:1111];
    [spritesToRemoveArray addObject:sprite1];
    sprite1.rotation = angle;
    sprite1.position = ccp( p.x, p.y);

    // Define the dynamic body.
    //Set up a 1m squared box in the physics world

    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(p.x/PTM_RATIO, p.y/PTM_RATIO-1.0);
    bodyDef.userData = sprite1;
    _footballBody = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    _footballBody->SetUserData(sprite1);
    // Define another box shape for our dynamic body.
    b2CircleShape dynamicBox;
    dynamicBox.m_radius = 0.35f;
    //dynamicBox.(.5f, .5f);//These are mid points for our 1m box

    // Define the dynamic body fixture.
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox; 
    fixtureDef.density = 20.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.9f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.6f;
    fixtureDef.userData = sprite1;
    fixtureDef.filter.groupIndex = -1;
    _footballFixture = _footballBody->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
    [sprite1 setPhysicsBody:_footballBody];



    float angle1 = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle);
    b2Vec2 vect = b2Vec2(cos(angle1)*120, sin(angle1)*120);
    b2Vec2 PointVector = _footballBody->GetPosition();
    _footballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(vect,PointVector);


    b2Vec2 targetPos = b2Vec2(body1->GetPosition());
    //if (_footballFixture->TestPoint(_footballBody->GetPosition())) {
    NSLog(@"\n Target postion = <%f,%f>",targetPos.x,targetPos.y);
    NSLog(@"\n football position = <%f,%f>",_footballBody->GetPosition().x/32.0,_footballBody->GetPosition().y/32.0);

        b2MouseJointDef md;
        md.bodyA = _groundBody;
        md.bodyB = _footballBody;
        md.target = targetPos;
        md.collideConnected = true;
        md.maxForce = 1000.0f * _footballBody->GetMass();
//        md.dampingRatio = 0;
//        md.frequencyHz = 100;
        _mouseJoint = (b2MouseJoint *) world->CreateJoint(&md);
        _footballBody->SetAwake(true);
    //}




}
```

Actually when I does this the ball should travel to the target point but here using the above method the ball is floating at the point where it created and slowly it moves eighter right edge of left edge.

I need suggestions from your side how can I resolve this.

Anyone's help is much appreciated.

Thanks all,

Comment: I got this working by replacing the md.target = targetPos; line of code to md.target = b2Vec2(_footballBody->GetPosition());. and adding the line at end of the method _mouseJoint->SetTarget(targetPos);

Comment: I am having a problem here too. As I am having obstacles between the ball and target postion. as the ball hits the obstacle it changing the direction away from the target position. Any help..??